# How add hdri image on sphere?

Tags: hdri

I want to make a mobile game with Unity.

My project would be an space game so for that I need a sphere to make the sky.

Can someone explain what I have to do, to have a sphere with an hdri picture mapped to it?

I watched dozen of tutorial to do that but either it is on the previous version of Blender or not the tutorial don't show what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple. Just use an Image Texture (your HDRI) for the object's material and connect it through an emission Shader so it emits light instead of being prone to shadows:

[image: World]

From inside the sphere, you can see the HDRI as you would as if it was connected through a World Shader:

[image: World2]